# Can't decompress with GZIP: Traceback error

Tags: python, compression, gzip, traceback

When I try to use GZIP to decompress it outputs an error called `Exception in Tkinter callback Traceback (most recent call last)`. The compression works and the file is put into an archive and I can open it.

```
import gzip
import os
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
import shutil
from contextlib import ExitStack
import json


def decomp(path):
    json.loads(path)
    str_path = str(path)
    dec = gzip.decompress(str_path)
    print("Decompressed")


def comp(path):
    with ExitStack() as stack:
        f_in = stack.enter_context(open(path, 'rb'))
        f_out = stack.enter_context(gzip.open(path + ".gz", 'wb'))
        shutil.copyfileobj(f_in, f_out)
```

Path is passed through as a string. Any help is appreciated.

EDIT:

More detail about the traceback:

Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter_*init*_.py", line 1884, in **call**
return self.func(*args)
File "C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Documents\Work\Compression_Project\project w zlib.py", line 77, in decompress_button
decomp(path=self.path)
File "C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Documents\Work\Compression_Project\project w zlib.py", line 12, in decomp
json.loads(path)
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json_*init*_.py", line 346, in loads
return _default_decoder.decode(s)
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: We need the traceback before we can tell what went wrong.

Comment: @BoarGules I added some more info about the traceback.

Comment: This has nothing to do with `gzip`. The traceback shows that the failure is here: `C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Documents\Work\Compression_Project\project w zlib.py", line 12, in decomp`  `json.loads(path)` and from the message it appears your code is trying to load an invalid (probably empty) JSON file.